# Looking for a query that eliminates near-repeats

Tags: postgresql, duplication

I have a database with four rows: county_a, county_b, flow_a_to_b, and flow_b_to_a. Essentially, the data is repeating in other rows, but the values are switched around. Here's an example:

Entry 1: Baltimore County, Baltimore City, 10, 1

Entry 2: Baltimore City, Baltimore County, 1, 10

These entries are technically different but they give me the same information. What kind of query could I write to eliminate the second value while keeping the first?

Comment: are the numbers alone sufficient enough to collapse the names?

Comment: Your version of Postgres and PostGis? Can there be NULL values? If so, do you consider them equal for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sense is that you're doing something wrong and need better tooling like PostGIS and PgRouting just from the problem you're describing but perhaps something like this will work,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  greatest(name1, name2),
  least(name1, name2),
  greatest(x1,x2),
  least(x1,x2)
FROM tbl;
```

If you're using PostGIS then you can use spatial equality,

```
SELECT max(coalesce(t1.name,t2.name))
FROM table AS t1
JOIN table AS t2
  ON ST_Equals(t1.line,t2.line)
GROUP BY ST_Equals(t1.line,t2.line);
```

If you're using [PgRouting](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.5/en/pgRouting-concepts.html#build-a-routing-topology) none of this matters because the edges become the same anyway. Edges are bidirectional.

Comment: I'm using PostGIS. Each entry has a line geometry attached, where the start node is the centroid of county_a while the end node is the centroid of county_b. While the lines are shaped the same, the geometries are technically different. Let me know if there are other ways to use PostGIS to solve this

Comment: I just tried your query and it appears to work. Thank you!

Comment: @DevinSimmons updated with postgis and pgrouting